# In the raft consensus algorithm, is this scene possible?

Tags: raft, paxos, leader-election

[image]
As shown in the picture, how was S2 elected leader for the third term?
The term of S2's latest log during the election was 1, so he could only get votes from S4.He will fail in this election.

here's the exam with answers.
[https://ongardie.net/static/raft/userstudy/rubric.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have no doubt about the answer，but I can't explain how S2 elected.
Could anyone help?

searched in google,github,stackoverflow.
discuss with friends.
And learned the MIT course about Raft.But I still think this scene is wrong

Comment: it does not look right, not even close :) - but I am taking my words back if the AI concurs the world